# NodeJS Express Project Structure

Tags: asp.net, node.js, architecture

In the ASP.Net Visual Studio ecosystem, I'm used to breaking my application into pieces or separate components via class libraries or separate projects within the same "solution" for purposes of separation of concern (DAL, BI, etc.).  They are then wired up by including them as references.

What is the correct and/or best practice method of doing this in the NodeJS w/ Express ecosystem?

Comment: This is pretty opionion based but I like the structure that is explained here: https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-project-structure-tutorial-node-js-at-scale/